# Не работает jQuery скрипт

Tags: jquery

Всем, привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так в моем выражении.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#container_logo p').hover(
        function(){
            $($this).animate(
            {
                text-shadow: "#363535 3px 3px 3px"
            },
            5000);
        },
        function(){
            $($this).animate(
            {
                text-shadow: "#363535 1px 1px 1px"
            },
            5000);
    });
</script>
```

Здесь вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/pZnWx/)

Я хочу, чтобы при наведении курсора на текст, тень изменялась.

Comment: $this - это не пхп

Comment: @ReinRaus - это уже разобрали, там пример есть.

Comment: Столько ошибок я еще не видел О_о

Comment: @IamS - можно было даже не комментировать, я сюда не готовый, красивой, рабочий код пришел показать!

Comment: @Артёмыч, Согласен, мастерство программиста заключается не в том, чтоб написать код без ошибок, а написать такой код, который смог бы работать с любыми ошибками.

Comment: @IamS ))) за такой комментарий жирный плюс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$($this).animate(
```

замените на

```
$(this).animate(
```

Comment: заменил ничего не происходит http://jsfiddle.net/pZnWx/1/

Comment: я что-то сильно сомневаюсь что на подобный аттрибут можно animate прикрутить

Comment: @eicto я пробовал без тире, ничего не происходит, а что посоветуете, мот альтернативу какую-нить...?

Comment: [через css3](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/pZnWx/2/) сделайте и не мучайтесь.

Comment: дело не в тире, а в том, что из себя представляет значение text-shadow.

Comment: Ооо спасибо, сделал по вашему примеру!

Answer (score 2):

Очень хорошо посоветовал товарищ [@eicto](/users/11304/eicto) сделать на **CSS**.

Реализовать можно это таким способом:

```
#container_logo p {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: #363535 1px 1px 1px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#container_logo p:hover {
    text-shadow: #363535 3px 3px 3px;
```

}

Comment: плюс только за комент!

Answer (score 2):

По-моему проще анимировать на CSS: [поправил ваш пример на JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhukovroman/pZnWx/4/). Решения для jQuery, как правило, требуют подключения какого-нибудь jQuery-плагина.

```
#container_logo p {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;

    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(54,53,53,1);

    font-variant: small-caps;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#container_logo p:hover {
    text-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(54,53,53,1);
}
```

Comment: @Zhukov Roman спасибо, такая альтернатива меня вполне устраивает!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.alexpeattie.com/projects/animate-textshadow/
Вот есть неплохой плагин для этих целей